# how to optimize a dart list with LIFO option to improve performance

Tags: flutter, list, dart, arraylist, linked-list

I have met some scenarios for a growable list that I want to check some conditions on the full list particularly the last element which added to list, In fact it have more probability of not satisfying our required condition,
is there any performance improved way in checking a condition for last elements in the list.

> for example pick the element from a list which have numeric values

```
var list= ["abc","cdef","gghih""asdffcf","a123ghjk"];
```

it is visible that or assumption to a developer that last few elements will be the required solution.

Comment: Can't you just do something like `functionThatChecksConditions(list[list.lenght - 1])` ?